# c++ GetPrivateProfileString read ini file from current directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ini

I'm creating a dll on c++. It is a Visual Studio project. The dll reads some data from ini file. I have decided to use GetPrivateProfileString function. It works almost completely. It does not see file in current directory. How can I provide this parameter (variable called path)?

How can I pass last parameter (path)

Code:

```
LPCTSTR path = L"\\test.ini";
TCHAR protocolChar[32];
int a = GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Connection"), _T("Protocol"), _T(""), protocolChar, 32, path);
```

String from test.ini:

```
[Connection]
Protocol = HTTP
```

I also tried this:

```
LPCTSTR path = L"test.ini";
```

But it did not help me

Comment: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - `If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory.`  Try constructing the full pathname, or at least remove the backslash from the beginning of the filename unless you're expecting it to be at the root of whatever the current drive is.

Comment: `LPCTSTR path = L"\\test.ini; `  To be consistent, you should use the _T() macro: `LPCTSTR path = _T("\\test.ini");`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
LPCTSTR path = _T(".\\test.ini");
```

`.` symbolises current directory. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
WCHAR   cfg_IniName[256];         

GetCurrentDirectory (MAX_PATH, cfg_IniName );    

wcscat ( cfg_IniName, L"\\test.ini" );
```

way to get full path