# Parameters of GetPrivateProfileInt method

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, ini

***Question*: How to use string/char* variable as the path parameter to GetPrivateProfileInt method.**

I m trying to use [GetPrivateProfileInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724345(v=vs.85).aspx) given for windows. The following code runs perfeclty without any issue:

```
int x = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"x",L"y",1,L"This\\is\\the\\path");
```

But in my case, the path is being passed to the function. Something like this:

```
void fun(std::string path)
{
  //error const char* is incampatible with LPCWSTR.
  int x = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"x",L"y",1,path.c_str());
}
```

In some attempts given below, x is recieving the default value. i.e. the path is not being passed to the  GetPrivateProfileInt method correctly.

Following are several other attempts made by me:

**Attempt1:**

```
// No error, default value is being read.
int x = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"x",L"y",1,(LPCTSTR)path.c_str());
```

**Attempt2:**

```
// No error, default value is being read.
int x = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"x",L"y",1,(wchar_t*)path.c_str());
```

**Attempt3:**

```
//_T() macro giving error.
// 'Ls' : undeclared identifier.identifier "Ls" is undefined.
LPCTSTR path_s = _T(path.c_str());
int x = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"x",L"y",1,path_s);
```

I went through the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138959/c-getprivateprofilestring-read-ini-file-from-current-directory) but not able find out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of the function, one takes UCS-2 characters (`GetPrivateProfileIntW`) and one takes `char` characters (`GetPrivateProfileIntA`).  There are no versions which allow you to mix the parameters.  Your options are to either change the *appname* and *keyname* parameters to single-byte to match your data

```
GetPrivateProfileIntA("x", "y", 1, path.c_str());
```

or to convert the last parameter to UCS-2 using `MultibyteToWideChar`, then call `GetPrivateProfileIntW`.

Pointer-casting is NOT a conversion of the character encoding, and will not work.  The compiler type system is there to help you, and making it shut up with a cast is nearly always the wrong thing to do (exception: the return value of `GetProcAddress` does need a cast).